# How many hidden layers are there in a Deep Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, deep-learning

can anybody tell me "usually" how many layers does a Deep Neural Network have? How deep is deep enough?

To my knowledge, it is still difficult to say the specific number of the hidden layers. But can anyone tell me, like some examples, how many hidden layers will researchers, developers use in their deep learning projects?

Many thanks.

Comment: That's not possible to answer properly since there is no specific "Deep Neural Network" but rather a collection of architectures that follow the deep learning paradigm. These are all quite different in their depth. If you're really interested you'll have to pick one and read on google scholar what the latest papers say.

Comment: @runDOSrun, so how scientists (that wrote papers) know the best hidden layers they need?  I read some papers and only read the results from their research. What methods?

Comment: @TanPhan trial and error mostly. Look up "hyperparameter optimization" techniques such as e.g. grid search, random search, or bayesian optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It totally depends on the problem you try do model. The more layers you have, the harder it's to train the network (more computation power needed). The deeper the layer is however, the more complex problems it can solve.

Geoffrey Hinton wrote in his [tutorial](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/nipstutorial/nipstut3.pdf):

> How many lines of code should an AI program use and how long should
>   each line be? – This is obviously a silly question.
>
> • Deep belief nets
>   give the creator a lot of freedom.
>
> – How best to make use of that
>   freedom depends on the task.
>
> – With enough narrow layers we can model
>   any distribution over binary vectors (Sutskever & Hinton, 2007)
>
> • If freedom scares you, stick to convex optimization of shallow models
>   that are obviously inadequate for doing Artificial Intelligence.

From what I know the number of layers usually is not really big. [Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842.pdf) ( *ImageNet Large-Scale Visual Recognition Challenge 2014*) e.g. google team used a net with 22 layers.

Comment: 22 layers is a **huge** number considering vanishing gradients and what people did before CNNs became popular. So I wouldn't call that "not really big". But again, that's a CNN and there are Deep Nets that wouldn't be able to handle that many layers.

Comment: @runDOSrun I agree, however if you don't know what's really going on behind the scenes, 22 layers may seem a suspiciously small number. BTW, vanishing gradient problem applies to gradient methods only. If you use PSO or GA algorithms for training, it doesn't occur. These methods are much slower though.

Comment: I know that but I'm not sure OP does. So giving any number is probably not helpful to him since his wording makes me unsure if he knows about the differences of architectures and training at all.

Comment: And they use ReLU,  ReLU doesn't face gradient vanishing problem as with sigmoid and tanh function.